# Getting date, month.year from timestamp string

Tags: php, datetime

I am getting timestamp from twitter api in this form `Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014`

I want to get month(i.e 3,4,12 etc), year from this string.

Here is the code. what is issue with it?
:

```
<?php

            $time = "Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014";
            $dt = new DateTime('@' . strtotime($time));
            $tweet_time = $dt->format('H:m:s');
            $tweet_dtm = $dt->format('Y:m:d');
            $year =  $dt->format('Y'); 
            $month =  $dt->format('m'); 
?>
```

It gives run time error

I dont understand what happened here. This code was working fine in March, I did not make change, even it started giving error when I tested in April. Any relevence?

see http://ideone.com/z2zmmV

**UPDATE**

Both answer works when I tested on Ideone, but when I use it in my code it gives error:

```
            foreach($tweets5 as $item)
            {
                    $text = $item->text;
        $text_id = $item->id;
                    $user_id = $item->user->id;
                    $name = $item->user->name;
        $constant = 'retweet';
        $time = $item->created_at;
                    //Up to this execution goes fine. After that it stop. any php adons which gives line no of error?
        $dt = new DateTime($time);
        $tweet_time = $dt->format('H:m:s');
        $tweet_dtm = $dt->format('Y:m:d');
        $year =  $dt->format('Y'); 
        $month =  $dt->format('m');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$time = "Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014";
            $dt = new DateTime($time);
            $tweet_time = $dt->format('H:m:s');
            $tweet_dtm = $dt->format('Y:m:d');
           echo $year =  $dt->format('Y'); 
           echo $month =  $dt->format('m'); 
//output 2014 03
```

You will need to use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse that date:

Comment: Indepedently when I run this it works, but when I use it in my actual script, it stop at this point

Comment: what is output of echo $time = $item->created_at;

Comment: `Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014`

Comment: for all in foreach? please show your all output in foreach for createat

Comment: Foreach executes only once, at `$dt = new DateTime($time);` it was getting stopeed

Comment: thanks dude, `$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s e Y', $time);
` helped me, can you please tell me reason

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s e Y', 'Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //2014-03-14
echo $date->format('Y'); //2014
echo $date->format('m'); //03
echo $date->format('d'); //14
```

Comment: Indepedently when I run this it works, but when I use it in my actual script, it stop at this point @Jay

Comment: @Programming_crazy Can you print the value of time variable?

Comment: Here is it: `Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014`

Comment: @Programming_crazy It seems that the $time is an object. Rather then passing $time try passing $time->text; I.e. DateTime($time->text)

Comment: thanks dude, `$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s e Y', $time);
` helped me